# Unity, adds pixels and colors to sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my original image (zoomed in):
[image]

When I use sprite 2D this is how the image looks like in the scene:
[image]

Notice the extra pixels and low opacity pixels that are added around image.

I did the following fixes, nothing worked:

- Filter Mode = No Filter
- Comparssion = High Quality
- Max Size = 64 (actual size) also tried increasing nothing changes.
- Generate mipmaps = did nothing
- anti aliasing disabled from quality
- Added pixel perfect camera

Note that the issue appears in sprite editor, so its a problem with importing the image\image settings. I want to use sprite 2d, for the sprite editor.

Comment: Use png, not jpg.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I do use PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved it was Compression set to "NONE", can't believe I missed it, it was set to high